Image detection with Yolo3 - Unable to open file (file signature not found)
When I trying to use ObjectDetection on an image with yolov3 I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bgre4\PycharmProjects\OpenEdu\CV.py", line 7, in <module>
    detector.loadModel()
  File "C:\Users\bgre4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\__init__.py", line 190, in loadModel
    model.load_weights(self.modelPath)
  File "C:\Users\bgre4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2294, in load_weights
    with h5py.File(filepath, 'r') as f:
  File "C:\Users\bgre4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 424, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size,
  File "C:\Users\bgre4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 190, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 96, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)

Here's code:
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath("yolov3.pt")
detector.loadModel()
custom = detector.CustomObjects(person=True)

for item in os.listdir('CV'):
    detections = detector.detectCustomObjectsFromImage(custom_objects=custom, input_image= f"CV/{item}",output_image_path= f"CV/new{item}", minimum_percentage_probability=50)

I downloaded file with yolo from https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/tree/master/imageai/Detection.
I've read about this issue that the file can be corrupted.
So the question is am I doing something wrong or the file is really corrupted?

I'm not familiar with that repo, so I cannot help much. But if you're using YOLOv3, you should use the actual Darknet/YOLO framework.  It does have python bindings (see src-python) and can be downloaded here:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents
